# Uncountable ordinals and graphs of functions

Tags: set-theory

Let $X$ be the first uncountable ordinal.  In other words $X$ is an uncountable set equipped with a well-ordering relation "$\leq $" such that, for every $x$ in $X$, the set
  $$
  \{y\in X:\  y\leq x\}
  $$
  is countable.
  Let
  $$
  T=\{(x, y)\in X\times X:\ y\leq x \},
  $$
  so that $T$ consist of everything below the diagonal in $X\times X$.

Let us agree to call a subset $G\subseteq T$ a *graph*, provided
  $$
  \big ((x,y_1)\in  G\big ) \ \wedge\ \big ((x,y_2)\in  G\big ) \ \Rightarrow \ y_1=y_2.
  $$
  Clearly these are precisely the graphs of $X$-valued functions $f$ defined on subsets of $X$, such that $f(x)\leq x$, for every $x$.

> Question:  Is it possible to write $T$ as the union  of a countable family  of graphs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a more general result here:

> Suppose $\mathcal{A}=(A_i)_{i\in I}$ is a collection of countable nonempty sets. Then the set $$[\mathcal{A}]=\{(a,i): a\in A_i\}$$ is the union of countably many graphs of functions.

When phrased this way it's much easier to think about. Simply fix surjections $b_i:\omega\rightarrow A_i$, and for $k\in\omega$ let $$f_k:I\rightarrow\bigcup\mathcal{A}:i\mapsto b_i(k).$$ Then the union of the graphs of the $f_k$s is exactly $[\mathcal{A}]$.

(Put another way, $f_k(i)=b_i(k)$ - basically, you have $I$-many "columns" of size $\le\omega$, and you view the whole grid as $\omega$-many "rows" of size $I$.)

*Of course, we use the axiom of choice when we pick the $b_i$s, and in the absence of choice can fail (and in particular the special case of your question can fail without choice). But that's a side point.*

Comment: Your definition $f_k(i)=b_i(k)$ reminds me that Attila Máté once told a class in combinatorial set theory that the main technique of that subject is interchanging the subscript and the argument.

Comment: Thanks, Noah.  Changing the perspective really made my question trivial!